# deleted css files are accessing and web application is running those files

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I made a static folder where I saved all css files to be used in my flask web development project. It is not reflecting the changes while I was doing some change .When I deleted that static folder then also it is accesing the files.
I have not clue from where it is accessing..

Please solve this problem
Thanks in advance
gallery.css file is  not present:-
[image]
but accessing this file:-
[image]

Comment: try to clean the cache of your chrome navigator

Comment: Enable `debug` and `reload` flags during development

Comment: Look up "cache busting" for explanations and workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try going to your project directory (not in your IDE, but the folder where the project is located)
find any/all directories named

```
__pycache__
```

and delete them.

clear all browser cache.

rerun the app in your IDE